# Reading files from a directory for current date

Tags: vb.net, file, filesystems

I have a shared directory where a report is being generated daily. I need to read the report of current date only and leave behind all the reports. I can't delete the old reports or rename them. Please advise if there is any way to do this.

Comment: also is there a way to automate this task, so I don't have to do this manually daily.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo("DirectoryPath")

Dim reports = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(file) file.CreationTime.Date = Date.Today)

For Each report In reports
    'DO Something...
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for that :). I have the directory path as http://test/....report.txt so how to get through that.

Comment: Try to put directory path  in `Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo("DirectoryPathHere")` and you can access to files modified today in For Each loop.

Comment: It might be prudent to check the `file.CreationTime.Date` too in case the `LastWriteTime` is not set, and use `file.LastWriteTime?.Date` in case the file system containing the file does not support LastWriteTime information (ref: [FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTime Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx)).